# WCF net.tcp client needs to run as administrator

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting, net.tcp

I have a self-hosted WCF service with SecurityMode set to None.
I have an installed WPF app that is attempting to call the service on a remote server.  If I do not run the app as administrator the connection fails.  However if I elevate the privileges and run as admin the connection and the call work as expected.

More strangeness: 
I created a simple console app and that seems to work fine as well.
If I run the WPF from a copied version of the app, not the installed version from the first part of this question, it runs fine as well.

What am I missing that might be causing this unexpected behavior.  As I am typing this question, I am thinking it might have something to do with permissions in the install directory?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Did you "install" from a zip file?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried replicating to no avail.  What should I be looking for?

Comment: Check the permissions on the user account the application is running under - that account will need to have admin privileges.

Comment: Some servers keep the files "blocked" if you brought them over from a zip. right click the files, go to properties, and see if they're blocked... http://superuser.com/a/38489

Comment: Tim: if I run the same application copied not installed it runs fine. David:  wouldn't the application not run if it was blocked?  It runs fine, it just doesn't do the WCF stuff.